# How does this line make my console application beep?

Tags: c#, windows

Came across this by accident. Can someone please explain why this gives a beep?

```
while (true)
{
      Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(7)));
}
```

Comment: Infinite loop is infinite.

Comment: char 7 is the bell character

Comment: @TaW good to know it gives no output though just beeps

Comment: That would depend on where you output it to. The console will beep, many other output devices try to print something, most likely a square

Comment: You can also use the character `\a` directly: `Console.WriteLine("\a");` I used to do this when I was still in school, to annoy people correcting the exercises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's the [Bell code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character).

> A bell code (sometimes bell character) is a device control code originally sent to ring a small electromechanical bell on tickers and other teleprinters and teletypewriters to alert operators at the other end of the line, often of an incoming message.

It's an old hack to make certain devices make noise when certain parts of a message are received (like, say the start or end). Your computer happens to be one of the devices that make a noise when that character is printed.

Comment: I can remember when I used a teletype and you sent the Bell code to actually ring a bell...

Answer (score 1):

That's the bell character (alt 7).
`Console.WriteLine("•")`(alt + num-7) would also make a beep. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character

Answer (score 1):

This come from a long time ago,

We use character codes for both control and data streams.

In the standar ascii charset, the 0x07 char is bell, this mandates to the receiver system to beep or alert to te user.

Other well know control codes are 0x10 and 0x13 (Line feed and carriage return, [in your screen and in printers])

Most of these are not noticeable and prints as an single icon o character, but your 0x07 char is a very special control code ;)